# Desire2Learn Valence Demographics not showing in web UI

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am using Desire2Learn Valence PHP API to create, retrieve and update users demographics as found here [Demographics (data types, fields, users and org units)](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/demographics.html). I am successful in creating and viewing demographics fields using the valence API calls.

The problem is that I cannot find anywhere in the web interface UI, where to view that students demographics fields that have been created using valence.

Does something need to be enabled in the DOME to view the demographics?
Or, are the demographic fields, only part of valence, and not the web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demographic fields are currently exposed in Valence only. We're looking at how they may be used in other parts of the system but have not included anything into the core UI just yet. We wanted to make this available to app developers and clients but didn't want them to have to wait for exposure in the UI.

There's some obvious places we may want to expose the fields but also lots places we haven't thought about that are important. We're interested in hearing more about where people would like to see these being used.